# Need to sort randomly generated numbers into numerical order

Tags: javascript

Struggling to sort random numbers into numerical order

added various sort functions

```
generateNumbers = () => {
    let lottoNum = [];
    while (lottoNum.length < 7) {
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1;
        if (lottoNum.indexOf(random) === -1) lottoNum.push(random);
    }

    return lottoNum.join(" ");
};

let btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function getNumbers() {
    const nums = generateNumbers();
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = nums;
});
```

Comment: so call sort()?

Comment: `lottoNum.sort((a, b) => a-b)`

Comment: Yeah, as said before, just `lottoNum.sort( (a, b) => a-b ).join(" ")`

Comment: Thanks Mark im pretty sure i tried that and came back unsorted however copied yours ans seems to work, (maybe missed a () out maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Just `sort` them:

```
return lottoNum.sort((a, b) => a - b).join(" ");
```

Descending order:

```
return lottoNum.sort((a, b) => b - a).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

to sort Array in javascript you can use sort keyword 
try this

```js
 return lottoNum.sort().join(" ");
```